# Accessing the PCI config space with Win32 API

Tags: windows, winapi, drivers, pci, pci-bus

Given the address of a PCI device (i.e. bus, device, function), how can one programatically read, using Win32 API calls in userspace, the config space (e.g. vendor ID, device ID) for that device?

On Linux, one openes the /sys/bus/pci/devices//config file and reads from the right offset.

Comment: In Windows I would try with [WMI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394582(v=vs.85).aspx) for something like this, [maybe the Win32_PnPEntity class can help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394353(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: BIOS data is mapped (readonly) to the registry at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Mssmbios\Data, also you can check this document "SMBIOS Support in Windows": http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/d/6/5d6eaf2b-7ddf-476b-93dc-7cf0072878e6/smbios.doc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [SetupDiGetClassDevs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551069(v=vs.85).aspx) API to traverse a list of devices. If you pass `PCI` in the `Enumerator` parameter, you can enumerate only PCI devices.